# How to modify pagination base_url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on pagination and I want to modify my pagination url from this:  http://localhost/Pedestana/index.php/Pengunjung/index/#desa/ (this is pagination offset) 
to this:
http://localhost/Pedestana/index.php/Pengunjung/index/ (this is pagination offset)/#desa. and when the page is loaded, it will scroll down to id #desa

I have tried change the `config['uri_segment']`, but it doesn't work properly.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->database();
    $jumlah_data = $this->model_desa->jumlah_data();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] =base_url().'index.php/Pengunjung/index/offset/#desa';
    $config['total_rows'] = $jumlah_data;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $from = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $config['uri_segment']='offset';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['kecamatan']=$this->model_kecamatan->kecamatan();
    $data['desa']=$this->model_desa- >data($config['per_page'],$from);
    $this->load->view('Pengunjung/index',$data);
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

if its okay  to generate link like this

```
http://localhost/Pedestana/Pengunjung/index/#desa?per_page=20
```

Then you can set:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] set to TRUE
```

And use Get method in place of:

```
$from = $this->uri->segment(3); //replace this with get method to get per_page data
```

i.e

```
$this->input->get('per_page');  //Get method to get per_page
```

You can see the link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

for its elaborated usage

Comment: it works but the page won't scroll down to id #desa